# Why does the interior of a subset $A \subset E^n$ have the same volume as the subset?

Tags: real-analysis

The official Question Statement is the following:

Show that if a subset $A \subset E^n$  has volume, then the interior of A has the same volume.

My guess is that the boundary can be shown to have zero volume, by showing its volume is $\lt \epsilon $ for any $\epsilon$. Therefore the volume of the interior must equal the volume of the entire subset. Unfortunately I am struggling with turning this into a proper proof, and to be frank I am not even sure that I am taking the correct approach.

Comment: What sort of sets $A$ are you considering? What does "have volume" mean?

Comment: It seems that you intend "has volume" to mean "is Jordan measurable". Some would say that "has volume" means "is Lebesgue measurable", and in this case your result is entirely false. As for a proof in the Jordan context, it really depends on your initial definition of Jordan measurability. For certain purposes "the boundary has Jordan measure zero" would be a valid way to define Jordan measurability.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose E is R-Q, the interior of E is empty and the volume of E is infinite.
You can also take E a ball of $R^n$ with its rational point removed. So your statement is not true.

Comment: This seems to depends on how the OP is defining volume. According to some definitions your set does not have a volume.